# Drawer Layout Will not preview. What's wrong?

Tags: android

I have browsed through all the questions and have tried absolutely everything I could find. I have tried

- Adding dependency for v4, v7, v13 to my graddle
- Copied the v4 and v13 jars to my libs folder
- tried to switch the compiled skd version, min sdk version, and target sdk version

I simply cannot get this drawer layout to preview. The app works fine when installed on a device and emulator. I am getting very frustrated tweeking a layout and having to launch all the way to a device to check how the layout looks. Can anyone figure this one out?

[image]

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the minSdkVersion to 14, change it to 17 (in the build.gradle) and it will renders correctly

Comment: No it does not for me